# How can I transfer information from one sheet in Excel to another using VBA based on specific conditions?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I want to take the values from Qty Produced from sheet PLAN to produced in sheet S corresponding to the correct product name and to the correct day of the week. [Sheet "S"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HIsqk.png)
[Sheet "PLAN"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ksmW1.png)
What I have tried so far is:
3 for loops - one iterating through the rows in sheet S where the Qty produces should be, one iterating through the rows in Sheet PLAN and one iterating through the colums in sheet S, together with 2 conditions - one making sure this is the same product and one making sure this is the correct date.
Here is the code I have:

```
Sub production()

    For k = 9 To 29 Step 4
        For n = 5 To 24

            If Sheets("plan").Cells(n, 3) = Sheets("s").Cells(k - 1, 1) Then

                For i = 3 To 23
                Set p = Sheets("S").Cells(k, i)
                    If Sheets("plan").Cells(n, 2) = Sheets("s").Cells(7, i) Then
                        p = Sheets("plan").Cells(n, 4).Value
                    End If
                Next i
            End If
        Next n
    Next k
End Sub
```

Currently, It does not yield anything.
Also, I have tried using excel formula Index and Match but with it the problem is that when you autofill it, the day column in sheet PLAN is changing.
Thank you in advance for the help!

Comment: Are the weekdays in both your sheets dates or text?

Comment: You should loop through your Plan every day, say at the end, and post the production of that day to your S sheet. You could do that by selecting a day that indicates the date you want to process. Nice plan, good strategy, but you didn't say that you wanted it. Will that idea suit your needs?

Comment: Yes, it is text and yes I want to do that but for everyday so far in the PLAN, however, I didn't quite well understand your suggestion.

Comment: At the start, you need to define which data to update. I suggest you update the numbers for the day (and later, but excluding TODAY()), meaning excluding any earlier days (on the presumption that they have been done before). So, you loop through all the days in PLAN and skip the ones you don't want. For the remaining you look for the day in S and post each number to the appropriate product. Unfortunately, you can't do that if you can't identify the days uniquely. That's why they must be dates in both sheets. Text won't do. Change and come back.

Comment: A date is represented by an integer, like 43909 which identifies March 19, 2020. You can enter this number in a cell (say A1), or `=TODAY(),` and then format the cell as `Date` (Right-click on the cell, select *Format Cells* and the *Number* tab) and you will see a date instead of the number but you can calculate with the number. Try [B1] `=A1 + 1`. You can apply the custom format "ddd" and only *Thu* and *Fri* will be displayed. To convert this to all-caps is another story but once your sheets identify each day uniquely by its date your project becomes feasible.

Comment: I have changed the dates and it worked that way. Wonderfully explained, thank you very much!

Comment: Is your problem solved, then?

Comment: Yes, but I don't know how to mark it as solved and close the case.

Comment: I'm glad you got your code to work. I have rephrased my advice and put it into an "Answer". If this helped you decisively please select it. Whether you do or don't - either way the thread will close itself by inaction. Thank you for caring.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest this flow for your program.

1. Define which data to update. I suggest you update the numbers for the day (and extend to include all days thereafter up to but excluding TODAY()), meaning excluding any earlier days on the presumption that they have been done before.
2. Loop through all the days in PLAN and skip the ones you don't want.
3. For the remaining you look for the day in S and post each number to the appropriate product.

In order to implement the above strategy you need to identify the days uniquely in both sheets. That's why they must all be be dates. Text won't do.

A date is represented by an integer, like 43909 which identifies March 19, 2020. You can enter this number in a cell (say A1), or =TODAY(), and then format the cell as `Date` (Right-click on the cell, select Format Cells and the Number tab) and you will see a date instead of the number but you can calculate with the number. Try [B1] =A1 + 1. You can apply the custom format "ddd" and only Thu and Fri will be displayed.

Use this method to create your captions. Just enter a date in the first caption cell, for example A3, enter `=A3 + 1` in A4 and copy the formula down as far as you need days in column A.

Answer (score 0):

Try the ADO code below, you have to add ADO library to your project:

```
Public Sub RunMe()
 Dim cnn As New ADODB.Connection
 Dim rst As New ADODB.Recordset
 Dim cmd As New ADODB.Command

 With cnx
    .Provider = "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0"
    .ConnectionString = "Data Source='" & ThisWorkbook.FullName & "'; " & "Extended 
 roperties='Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1'"
    .Open
End With


'setup the command
Set cmd.ActiveConnection = cnx
cmd.CommandType = adCmdText
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM [OutPutSheet$] where [ColumnName]=" & "'AnyValueOrVariable'"
rst.CursorLocation = adUseClient
rst.CursorType = adOpenDynamic
rst.LockType = adLockOptimistic

'open the connection
rst.Open cmd

'Assuming that you want to get the data from A2, or else you can even make it more 
'dynamic
Sheets("plan").Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rst


'disconnect the recordset
Set rst.ActiveConnection = Nothing
'disconnect the connection
Set cnx = Nothing

End Sub
```

You can state the conditions in the sql statement.